# using coinbase with uc_bitcoin drupal module

Tags: exchange-rate, php

I need a simple hack to change the Drupal `uc_bitcoin` modules code so it gets the exchange rate from Coinbase, it is designed to use MtGox. I want to avoid using the entire coinbase API because I just want the exchange rate, not the kitchen sink. There is a lot of documentation there.

I have found the code in the `uc_bitcoin` drupal module which gets the information from MtGox. It needs some simple changes so it gets this data from Coinbase. Since both are so different, and I'm not fluent with PHP I thought someone might be able to help me with this.

Here is the code which gets the exchange rate from MtGox:

```
function uc_bitcoin_exchange_rate($order) {

  static $rate;

  if(isset($rate)) {
    return $rate;
  }

  if ($order->currency == 'BTC') {
    // BTC 1:1
    return 1;
  }

  // Supported MtGox currencies, Dec 15 2012
  $mtGox_currencies = array(
    'USD',
    'EUR',
    'JPY',
    'CAD',
    'GBP',
    'CHF',
    'RUB',
    'AUD',
    'SEK',
    'DKK',
    'HKD',
    'PLN',
    'CNY',
    'SGD',
    'THB',
    'NZD',
    'NOK'
  );

  // @todo add cache
  if (in_array($order->currency, $mtGox_currencies)) {
    if ($response = drupal_http_request('https://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTC' . $order->currency . '/ticker')) { 
      if ($response->code == 200) {
        $data = json_decode($response->data);
        if(!empty($data->return->avg->value)) {
          $rate = $data->return->avg->value;
        }
      }
    }
  }

// @todo add cache
  if (in_array($order->currency, $mtGox_currencies)) {
    if ($response = drupal_http_request('https://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTC' . $order->currency . '/ticker')) { 
      if ($response->code == 200) {
        $data = json_decode($response->data);
        if(!empty($data->return->avg->value)) {
          $rate = $data->return->avg->value;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!$rate || !is_numeric($rate)) {
    watchdog('uc_bitcoin', 'MtGox lookup - Unable to get current exchange rate', WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    $rate = FALSE; // just to be super sure.
  }

  return $rate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with drupal, and I've never used the module you're talking about, but I'll take a shot at it:

```
function uc_bitcoin_exchange_rate($order) {
  static $data;
  $rate = FALSE;
  $currency = $order->currency;
  $currency_code = 'btc_to_' . strtolower($currency);

  if ($currency == 'BTC') {
    // BTC 1:1
    return 1;
  }
  if (!isset($data) {
    if ($response = drupal_http_request('https://api.coinbase.com/v1/currencies/exchange_rates')) {
      if ($response->code == 200) {
        $data = json_decode($response->data);
        $rate = $data[$currency_code];
      }
    }
  }

  if (!is_numeric($rate)) {
    watchdog('uc_bitcoin', 'CoinBase lookup - Unable to get current exchange rate', WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    $rate = FALSE; // just to be super sure.
  }

  return $rate;
}
```

Comment: Getting this error: `syntax error, unexpected {` on line 7 of this code. I can't figure out why, everything looks fine.

Comment: Found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

https://dgtlmoon.com/how_configuring_drupals_ubercart_bitcoin_payment_module

unfortunately it needs to communicate with a real 'bitcoind' instance via JSON/XMLRPC, I'm not sure if blockchain.info will provide this?